# Cambiar el color de fondo de un widget Treeview en tkinter según el resultado de una consulta

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

Quiero cambiar el color de fondo de un treeview según el resultado de una consulta, si  condiquery(argumento de condición) es igual a "", entonces el color de fondo debe ser "blanco" y si la condición es diferente, el color debe ser "azul claro".

Este código funciona bien, pero solo por primera vez (el color solo cambia dos veces, de blanco a azul claro, y el resto de las veces queda con color azul claro)

¿Alguien me ayudaría?

```
#Funcion Query Traer Pacientes
    def get_pacientes(self, condiquery):
        #limpio el color de fondo
        self.pac_win.style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, background='white', font=('Lucida Console', 9)) # Formato  del Cuerpo
        global acu_name
        self.acu_name=self.acu_name+1
        print(self.acu_name)
        #Limpio la tabla de pacietnes
        records = self.pac_win.pactree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.pac_win.pactree.delete(element)
        #Consulto los pacientes
        query = 'SELECT * from Padron where Status = 1 ORDER BY Paciente ASC'
        if condiquery !="":
            query = condiquery
            self.pac_win.style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, background='light blue', font=('Lucida Console', 9)) # Formato  del Cuerpo
        dbregpac = self.run_queries(query)
        #lleno la tabla 
        for row in dbregpac:
            self.pac_win.pactree.insert("",0,text = row[0], values = row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que hago normalmente es definir un estilo y luego con el atributo `style` se lo aplico.

En este ejemplo, al apretar los botones se modifica el estilo y se aplica automáticamente al Treeview.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

ventana = tk.Tk()

estilo = ttk.Style()

estilo.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0,
                 bd=0, background='light blue', font=('Lucida Console', 9))

tree = ttk.Treeview(ventana, columns=("Nombres", "Apellidos"),
                    selectmode='browse', style="mystyle.Treeview")

tree.insert('', 'end', text="Esteban",
               values="Quito")

tree.heading("#0", text="Nombre")
tree.heading("#1", text="Apellido")

tree.pack()

tk.Button(ventana, text="Cambiar light blue", command=lambda:(estilo.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0,
                   bd=0, background='light blue', font=('Lucida Console', 9)))).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

tk.Button(ventana, text="Cambiar white", command=lambda:(estilo.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0,
                   bd=0, background='white', font=('Lucida Console', 9)))).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

ventana.geometry("400x400")
ventana.mainloop()
```

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Eduardo, cree varios estilos con tu técnica y luego los voy aplicando. Gracias